# Regex to allow all but the character 0 on its own

Tags: regex

I want to create a regex to that will allow numbers and or characters but not 0 (zero) on its own.

This is what I have so far whilst playing with regex101.com

```
/^([^0])([a-z1-9])*$/img
```

It matches the last 3 items but I also need it to match the 00 one.

```
0
00
12
22344
sometext
```

How can I do this, how can I write "if its 0 on its own I don't want it, but anything else I do want it"?

Comment: Use `/^(?!0$)[a-z\d]+$/gm`

Comment: And thats the answer, many thanks @anubhava

Comment: Reopening because it is not correct dupe as it is not just match everything but specific pattern. Even main body `[a-z1-9]` requires a tweak here.

Comment: Here is another option `\b[^0\s]\b|\b\w{2,}`

Comment: @Daniel: That will also match a single `_` but OP only wanted alphanumeric (as per the attempted regex)

Comment: Ah, right... Thanks for pointing that out @anubhava

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead to disallow just `0` and then match 1+ alphanumeric in the match to allow matching `0`s:

```sh
^(?!0$)[a-z\d]+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KjFLFO/1)

- `(?!0$)` is negative lookahead after start position so that we fail the match if just `0` appears in input.
- `[a-z\d]+` matches 1 or more of a lowercase letter or a digit.

Comment: Thanks for that and  adding a bit extra explanation, I don't do them enough, but did see it call it a lookahead in regex101,  many thanks